# How to get transaction details in notify_url page in paypal

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

In paypal notify_url page I am not getting any values when I use cmd value as _cart.How can  I get the transaction details in notify_url page

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST" name="_xclick" id="paypal_form">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<!-- The business email address, where you want to receive the payment -->
<!--<input type="hidden" name="business" value="yesidealpayment@gmail.com" />-->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="arun_1260247381_per@galtechsupport.us" />
<!-- The customer email address -->

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="<?php echo ucfirst($couponname); ?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="<?php echo $total_payable_amount; ?>" />
<!--<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD" />-->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25.58" /> 
<!-- Where you want to return after PayPal Payment -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://yes-i-deal.com.au/test/paypal_ipn.php" />
<!-- A back-end notification send to the specific page after successful payment  -->
<!--<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yes-i-deal.com.au/test/paypal.php" />-->
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yes-i-deal.com.au/test/paypal_ipn.php" />
<!-- Where you want to return after cancel the PayPal Payment  -->
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://yes-i-deal.com.au/" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $coupon_id."_".$userid;?>" />  




            <input type="image" name="submit"   src="http://yes-i-deal.com.au/themes/green/images/Buy-Now-Button.png" />
</form>
```

In my notify_url page I am getting values as

```
 session_start(); 
require("ipn_cls1.php");
 $paypal_info = $_POST; 
print_r($paypal_info); 
$paypal_ipn = new paypal_ipn($paypal_info); 
$payment_status = trim($paypal_info['payment_status']); // Si Completed : tout est OK echo 
$payment_amount = trim($paypal_info['mc_gross']);
```

Comment: can you show your notify_url page code..? notify_url page gets POST data from paypal, so check POST data..

Comment: when I use cmd value as _xclick I am getting the details but when using _cart not getting.      My notify_url page I am getting value as session_start();
require("ipn_cls1.php");
$paypal_info = $_POST;
print_r($paypal_info);
$paypal_ipn = new paypal_ipn($paypal_info);

/////////////////////////
echo "status".$payment_status = trim($paypal_info['payment_status']);  // Si Completed : tout est OK
echo "status1".$payment_amount = trim($paypal_info['mc_gross']);

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with paypal adaptive payments in my current project. i have given my

notify_url as http://mysite.com/payment-success. In this page, i simply coded

$request = $_POST;

mail('myid@myaccount', $request);

and then i sent the transaction result to my mail to view.

Note, here in my mail i can able to see the transaction results and if i insert into database, it is inserting but i cant see the transaction results in my page. Try sending to your mail the transaction results.

Comment: when i use to send transaction details to my mail I am getting error in that page as Warning: mail() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given in /home/yesid984/public_html/test/paypal_ipn.php on line 16

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/yesid984/public_html/test/paypal_ipn.php on line 86

Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::is_verified() in /home/yesid984/public_html/test/paypal_ipn.php on line 98 and I am not getting any mail

Comment: yes sreelatha mail requires 3 parameters. mail('id@youaccount', 'title', $request)

Comment: how to get custom value. I changed the mail() to like mail('id@youaccount', 'title', $request). then also i am not getting any mail.I need the custom value how can I get it...

Comment: are you trying in localhost or live

Comment: hey i tried your test form with my paypal account and returns some data. my code is here and put this and test it.$req = '';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {  
 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1){  
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
 } 
 else { 
  $value = urlencode($value); 
 } 
 $req .= "&$key=$value"; 
}
print($req);

Answer (score 0):

Create paypal_ipn.php file and place php code in it.

```
    // Response from Paypal
    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];
    $data['invoice']            = $_POST['invoice'];
    $data['paypallog']          = $req;

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
    } else {    


        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            ////mail('atiftariq80@gmail.com','Step 9','Step 9');        
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (true || strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                ////mail('atiftariq80@gmail.com','PAYMENT VALID','PAYMENT VALID');  

            // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
            $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
            $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
            // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
            if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){               
            //----------------- INSERT RECORDS TO DATABASE-------------------------------------
            if ($data['invoice']=='basic') {
                $price = 39;
            } else { 
                $price = 159;
            }
            $this->user_model->update_user(
                array(
                    'id' => $data['custom'],
                    'user_status' => 1,
                    'payment_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()),
                    'next_payment_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+32 days')),
                    'user_package' => $data['invoice'],
                    'package_price' => $price
                )
            );
            $data2 = array('id' => '',
            'txn_id' => $data['txn_id'],
            'amount' => $data['payment_amount'],
            'mode ' => $data['payment_status'],
            'paypal_log' => $data['paypallog'],
            'user_id' => $data['custom'],
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())

            );
            $this->db->insert('tbl_paypal_log', $data2);
            //----------------- INSERT RECORDS TO DATABASE-------------------------------------
            }else{                  
            // Payment made but data has been changed
            // E-mail admin or alert user
            }                       

        } elseif ($res=='INVALID') {

                // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY! 
                // E-mail admin or alert user
                ////mail('atiftariq80@gmail.com','PAYMENT INVALID AND INVESTIGATE MANUALY','PAYMENT INVALID AND INVESTIGATE MANUALY');  

        }       
        }       
    fclose ($fp);
    }
```

Comment: what is check_txnid and check_price ?
where you defined these all ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [really good guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) and understanding how they work. This guide provides you the steps you need to have your `notify_url` working properly.

There are [good code samples](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) provided by Paypal that do the validation response for you, which is really nice. You can use these are the starting point for your own.