# Payment with PayPal hangs inside the notify_url page

Tags: php, paypal

I have this page to pay with paypal, and receive the notification in "notify_url". The purchase goes well but fails to receive the notification. Everything is fine until it reaches these two lines: `$valid_txnid = check_txnid ($data ['txn_id']);$valid_price = check_price ($data ['payment_amount'], $data ['item_number']);`
where the program hangs. (I know it because I have sent emails from various points of the program until I get there that I do not receive anything).
And also I don't know where the `check_txnid ()` and `check_price ()` functions come from, which I don't see defined anywhere. The code is taken from this other post: [How to get transaction details in notify_url page in paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949508/how-to-get-transaction-details-in-notify-url-page-in-paypal)

index.php

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-pwrdu1932120@business.example.com" />

<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MiArticulo" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" value="19" name="invoice">

<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://infrangible-discoun.000webhostapp.com/pruebaPaypal/notifyUrl.php">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" >
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://infrangible-discoun.000webhostapp.com/paypal4/newfile1.php">  
<input type="image" border="0" name="paypal" src="images/btn_paypal_nl.gif" onClick=""/>
</form>
```

notifyUrl.php

```
<?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require("conexion.php");

require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';

    // Response from Paypal
    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    //$value = urlencode($value);
    $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];
    $data['invoice']            = $_POST['invoice'];
    $data['paypallog']          = $req;
       
    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
    if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR       
    } else {    
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        ////mail('atiftariq80@gmail.com','Step 9','Step 9');        
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (true || strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            ////mail('atiftariq80@gmail.com','PAYMENT VALID','PAYMENT VALID');      
        // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
        $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);            
        $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
        // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
        if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){  //doesn't pass this if.             
        //----------------- INSERT RECORDS TO DATABASE-------------------------------------                              
        $name=$_POST['item_name'];
        mysqli_query($db,"insert into ventas value(0,'$name')");
        
        if ($data['invoice']=='basic') {
            $price = 39;
        } else { 
            $price = 159;
        }
        $this->user_model->update_user(
            array(
                'id' => $data['custom'],
                'user_status' => 1,
                'payment_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()),
                'next_payment_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+32 days')),
                'user_package' => $data['invoice'],
                'package_price' => $price
            )
        );
        $data2 = array('id' => '',
        'txn_id' => $data['txn_id'],
        'amount' => $data['payment_amount'],
        'mode ' => $data['payment_status'],
        'paypal_log' => $data['paypallog'],
        'user_id' => $data['custom'],
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())
        );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_paypal_log', $data2);   
        //----------------- INSERT RECORDS TO DATABASE-------------------------------------
        }else{    
         // Payment made but data has been changed
        // E-mail admin or alert user

        }                       
    } elseif ($res=='INVALID') {
            // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY! 
            // E-mail admin or alert user
            ////mail('atiftariq80@gmail.com','PAYMENT INVALID AND INVESTIGATE MANUALY','PAYMENT INVALID AND INVESTIGATE MANUALY');  
    }       
    }       
    fclose ($fp);
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know where the check_txnid () and check_price () functions come from, which I don't see defined anywhere.

That seems to be your problem. Don't call functions that don't exist.

If you want to to check the transaction ID and the price are unique and  valid for what you are offering, create actual functions that actually do this.

You could for example use 'custom' or 'invoice' to match against an existing order record in your database and validate the price corresponds, if you provided such a unique number to PayPal as part of the transaction.

Comment: but the problem is that I still don't have anything in the database. I was thinking of adding them to the database right at that point where it hangs.

Comment: The point of validation is to do it before adding things to the database. And you are calling non-existent validation functions, which will cause your code to completely fail. So you need to resolve this obvious problem, even if it means not doing validation for now, and proceed with whatever you actually do want to accomplish.

Comment: ok, I have to check that there is no item with the "txn_id" in the database. But ... and the price and amount. Do I also have to check that there are none already in the database?

Comment: You have to do what you want to do.  This spot is where your own validation and business logic goes, using the information in the IPN.

Comment: What does look quite wrong is earlier in the code where you are checking for a 'VERIFIED' response from the postback to PayPal. It looks like that if statement was hardcoded to always be "true", the check that looks for this verification from PayPal. That's quite obviously bad.

Comment: And how is the verification supposed to be done?

Comment: Have you read the IPN documentation? Which part of it wasn't clear? See steps 3 and 4 here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNImplementation/#ipn-listener-request-response-flow